# Extract taxonomy terms in wp_query

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have custom post types with taxonomies in them (for example Custom post type: Recipes; Taxonomies in the Recipes: Ingredients, Preparation Time, Difficulty).
In my homepage I want to run wp_query to display the latest 5 Recipes. So far so good, but when I can't manage to get the taxonomy entries for the post

I use the following code:

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'ratings_average', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_type' => 'muffins', 'showposts' => 1) );   
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="recipe">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(272,150)); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"><p class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <p class="recipe-contents"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></a>
        <ul>
            <li>Preparation time: (I need function to extract the taxonomy term for this post - The taxonomy is 'time')</li>
            <li>Difficulty: (same here ... the taxonomy is 'difficulty'</li>
            <li>Servings: (and once again the taxonomy is 'servings'</li>
        </ul>    
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do something with `the_terms` which is the WordPress function for pulling out taxonomy data.

Something similar to below:

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'meta_key' => 'ratings_average', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_type' => 'muffins', 'showposts' => 1) );   
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="recipe">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(272,150)); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"><p class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <p class="recipe-contents"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p></a>
        <ul>
            <li>Preparation time: <?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'time'); ?> </li>
            <li>Difficulty: <?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'difficulty'); ?></li>
            <li>Servings: <?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'servings'); ?></li>
        </ul>    
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

You can read more about `the_terms()` [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_terms) and how you can better use it with more styling, separators etc.

Hopefully this should answer your question.

Comment: This is just perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for the fast and accurate help. And also I will do my best to learn more on my own, but this is actually my first project :)

Comment: Haha don't worry fella, we all have to start somewhere :). Any more problems, just post em up :).